# Python: Combine several nested lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a bunch of lists like the following two:

```
['a', ['b', ['x', '1'], ['y', '2']]]
['a', ['c', ['xx', '4'], ['gg', ['m', '3']]]]
```

What is the easiest way to combine all of them into a single dictionary that looks like:

```
{'a': {
    'b': {
        'x':1,
        'y':2
    }
    'c': {
        'xx':4,
        'gg': {
            'm':3
        }
    }
}
```

The depth of nesting is variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very crude implementation, it does not handle weird cases such as lists having less than two elements and it overwrites duplicate keys, but its' something to get you started:

```
l1 = ['a', ['b', ['x', '1'], ['y', '2']]]
l2 = ['a', ['c', ['xx', '4'], ['gg', ['m', '3']]]]

def combine(d, l):
    if not l[0] in d:
        d[l[0]] = {}

    for v in l[1:]:
        if type(v) == list:
            combine(d[l[0]],v)
        else:
            d[l[0]] = v

h = {}
combine(h, l1)
combine(h, l2)
print h
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'c': {'gg': {'m': '3'}, 'xx': '4'}, 'b': {'y': '2', 'x': '1'}}}
```

Comment: Pretty awesome! And it works too. I need to sit and see how it works. 

Good news about the input is that lists always have 2 elements and unique keys. I just tested it on a 100+ lists 10 levels deep and it went well.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really 'pythonic' but i dont see a good way to do this without recursion

```
def listToDict(l):
    if type(l) != type([]): return l
    return {l[0] : listToDict(l[1])}
```

Comment: Your answer is much prettier +1

Comment: thanks. i think it makes some assumptions bout the input, but as long as it comes formatted like OP said it should be fine

Comment: lol except that it doesnt work right.  i gotta play with this a little more

Answer (score 1):

It made the most sense to me to break this problem into two parts (well, that and I misread the question the first time through..'S)

#### transformation

The first part transforms the `[key, list1, list2]` data structure into nested dictionaries:

```
def recdict(elements):
    """Create recursive dictionaries from [k, v1, v2, ...] lists.

    >>> import pprint, functools
    >>> pprint = functools.partial(pprint.pprint, width=2)
    >>> pprint(recdict(['a', ['b', ['x', '1'], ['y', '2']]]))
    {'a': {'b': {'x': '1',
                 'y': '2'}}}
    >>> pprint(recdict(['a', ['c', ['xx', '4'], ['gg', ['m', '3']]]]))
    {'a': {'c': {'gg': {'m': '3'},
                 'xx': '4'}}}
    """

    def rec(item):
        if isinstance(item[1], list):
            return [item[0], dict(rec(e) for e in item[1:])]

        return item

    return dict([rec(elements)])
```

It expects that

- every list has at least two elements
- the first element of every list is a key
- if the second element of a list is a list, then all subsequent elements are also lists; these are combined into a dictionary.

The tricky bit (at least for me) was realizing that you have to return a list from the recursive function rather than a dictionary.  Otherwise, you can't combine the parallel lists that form the second and third elements of some of the lists.

To make this more generally useful (i.e. to tuples and other sequences), I would change

```
if isinstance(item[1], list):
```

to

```
if (isinstance(item[1], collections.Sequence)
    and not isinstance(item[1], basestring)):
```

You can also make it work for any iterable but that requires a little bit of reorganization.

#### merging

The second part merges the dictionaries that result from running the first routine on the two given data structures.  I think this will recursively merge any number of dictionaries that don't have conflicting keys, though I didn't really test it for anything other than this use case.

```
def mergedicts(*dicts):
    """Recursively merge an arbitrary number of dictionaries.
    >>> import pprint
    >>> d1 = {'a': {'b': {'x': '1',
    ...                   'y': '2'}}}
    >>> d2 = {'a': {'c': {'gg': {'m': '3'},
    ...                   'xx': '4'}}}
    >>> pprint.pprint(mergedicts(d1, d2), width=2)
    {'a': {'b': {'x': '1',
                 'y': '2'},
           'c': {'gg': {'m': '3'},
                 'xx': '4'}}}
    """

    keys = set(k for d in dicts for k in d)

    def vals(key):
        """Returns all values for `key` in all `dicts`."""
        withkey = (d for d in dicts if d.has_key(key))
        return [d[key] for d in withkey]

    def recurse(*values):
        """Recurse if the values are dictionaries."""
        if isinstance(values[0], dict):
            return mergedicts(*values)
        if len(values) == 1:
            return values[0]
        raise TypeError("Multiple non-dictionary values for a key.")

    return dict((key, recurse(*vals(key))) for key in keys)
```

Comment: aaah, comprehension on arguments but not into a list.  i beat myself up dancing around that idea for too damn long lol

Comment: @jon_darkstar: It did require some persistence.  Funny how sometimes the shortest functions take the most time to write.

Comment: hah.  i tried using the non-existent 'dictionary comprehension' about 100 times, and quite quickly/easily wrote a solution that was concise and correct aside from wrapping every dict in a superfluous list.  i just failed to connect the dots and use `dict` constructor like you have.  well done

Comment: @jon_darkstar: yeah, passing `dict` a `(key, value)` generator expression is pretty much the same thing as using a dict comprehension, from what I can tell.  But I'm still on Python 2.6 so I haven't really checked them out yet.